# Java Threads, join() taking too long?

Tags: java, multithreading, join

So I have some code, I am creating 6 threads, in my main thread, that run some code. I start the threads. I then call `join()` on the threads, so that the main thread waits for them all to die before continuing with execution.

Now, I am using some really basic and most likely inaccurate way to measure how long my code takes to run. Just calls to get the system time at the start, the end, and then print the difference.

Lets say it is taking, for example, around 500ms to run all of my code.

I decided to remove the calls to `join()` for each thread, and instead I just told my main thread to sleep for 20ms. This resulted in my code finishing in around 200ms, and the main thread managed to continue with execution with the proper data from the worker threads - i.e. the 6 worker threads must have finished in that 20ms wait.

THEREFORE, why is it taking so much longer when I use .join on each worker thread? Naturally, I cannot keep the call in the main method to `sleep(20)`, and would rather use something like `join()`'s

Comment: The difference is that `join` is a correct solution, while `sleep` is not. It probably works because of some coincidence due to the actual code you wrote, but it is not guaranteed to always work. I think you should write some significant code to make things clearer.

Comment: Could you have each thread print something to confirm they are done.

Comment: Are the computations done by the 6 threads CPU intensive?

Comment: It looks like the worker thread doesn't die immediately after the work is done.

Comment: Are you finding the proper data from the worker threads by having the worker threads print the results themselves?  If so, try calling setDaemon(true) on the threads first, and you'll find they won't actually finish.  By default, main will wait until all threads are done.

Comment: The worker threads all access a global ConcurrentLinkedQueue and dump data into a global ConcurrentHashMap. I populate the queue in the main thread, then create the worker threads and have it process data based on what is in the queue, and then deliver it to the hashmap. Then when the worker thread dies, the main thread continues to print data from the hashmap. I could try and write some code to make things clearer, but it will take some time

Answer (score 3):

The problem with multi-threaded bugs is you can appear to be working when it is not working reliably.  It is possible your threads are doing something you don't need at the end, or you joining thread doesn't use the results right away.  In any case, I suggest you wait for the result correctly.

BTW I would use an ExecutorService as this allows you to recycle your threads and wait for just the results you need in the form of a `Future<MyResult>` note this also captures and Exception/Error thrown as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that your code is simply not getting finished if you take out the joins.  If your main function exits without joining on all of its threads, then it is possible some are getting set as daemon threads via setDaemon(), which would stop the program cleanup from waiting on them.

Do you own all the code involved?